# send and decode JSON array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to encode and send JSON array to php page and add it to mysql:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'naujas.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ({
        json: JSON.stringify(data)
    }),
    success: function () {
        $('#naujas').load('naujas.php');
    }
});
```

But I think its not working I'm getting response from php like that: `pav=1&ppav=2&kiekis=3&kaina=4d&ppav=5&kiekis=6&kaina=7&ppav=8&kiekis=9&kaina=0`

php file

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);
    echo $json;
?>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: .serialize() gives you a query string,  .serializeArray() might be closer to what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray().reduce( function(obj,cur){
    obj[cur.name] = cur.value;
    return obj;
},{});
```

*Explanation*:

- [**.serializeArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns an array, which has following structure:

  ```
  [ {name:"inputname1",value:"inputvalue1"},
    {name:"inputname2",value:"inputvalue2"},
    //---------------------------------------
    {name:"inputnamen",value:"inputvaluen"} ]
  ```
- [**.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function converts that array to object:

  ```
  { "inputname1":"inputvalue1",
    "inputname2":"inputvalue2",
    //---------------------------------------
    "inputnamen":"inputvaluen" }
  ```

Comment: Your edited code gives me only last form fields values not all array.

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė So you have multiple forms? Do I understand right?

Comment: well, form is one, but I can add additional rows set to it

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė Make sure, that when you add/remove/modify new input elements, those elements *are inside of the `form` tag*.

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: 'json'` already tell jQuery to post the data in a json format.

All you need to do is to post your data, something like this:

`data: (data),`

The problem comes from converting your object to a string representation (stringify).

Comment: `dataType` specifies the *response-body* type,not the *request-body* type !

Comment: If you only just do data: data you might run into a similar issue like I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385668/js-ajax-calling-php-and-getting-ajax-call-data

Comment: @Engineer: Upvoted, you are right and I was off-track anyway with my answer, I misunderstood OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use php stripslashes

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

I think it's something like this

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']));
```